# How to change only specific table row in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I need your help

I've got such a structure like below:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="messageText">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.MESSAGE' | translate }}</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length < 30">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 30)}}</span>

        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded == false">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
          <span class="show-more" (click)="expanded = true">more</span>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded == true">{{this.row.messageText}}
            <span class="show-more" (click)="this.expanded = false">less</span>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf="!row.messageText">-----</span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

This works as a table with some text in table cells. After clicking *more* the text in table cell expands to show entire content. If I click *less*, then the text go back to its short size.

The problem is when I click on *more* in the cell, every cell in table expand to show full text. I'd like to expand only specific table cell (that one where I clicked the *more* button).

I will be grateful for your ideas and solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this : `it wil be working for me to set true or false specific row`

```
<span *ngIf="(row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && (row.expanded == false || !row.expanded))">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
    <span class="show-more" (click)="row.expanded = true">more</span>
</span>
<span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && row.expanded == true">{{this.row.messageText}}
    <span class="show-more" (click)="row.expanded = false">less</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the expanded variable for all rows. You need separate variable for each row. Maybe you can add expanded property to each row object, initialize it to false and then change that.

```
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length < 30">{{row.messageText}}</span>

        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && row.expanded == false">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
          <span class="show-more" (click)="row.expanded = true">more</span>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && row.expanded == true">{{this.row.messageText}}
            <span class="show-more" (click)="row.expanded = false">less</span>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf="!row.messageText">-----</span>
      </mat-cell>
```